# Massive symbolic link creation using for loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link

I just wondering myself if it would be possible to create massive amount of symbolic links using a for loop?

For exemple, I have a lot of directory on my /tmp directory (I know, not recommanded) and I do not want to move them out.

Instead I just want to have them on my root directory using symbolic links.

Here is what I did, but unfortunatly, do not work at all:

```
for directories in /tmp/; do ln -s /tmp/$directories /$directories; done
```

So if someone could bring me a hint, it would be wonderfull ;-)
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
cd /tmp && for i in `ls `; do ln -s $i /$i; done
```

Comment: this will symlink files and is dangerous because it does not handle names with spaces properly

Answer (score 1):

```
for directories in `find /tmp/ -type d`
do
  ln -s /tmp/$directories /$directories;
done
```

Comment: Yep, your answer is right, you just forgot the ln -s command ;-)

Comment: well the one above is quite nicer then mine!

Comment: this is dangerous and wont work if directory name has spaces

Comment: Could you explain, why it's dangerous in your opinion?

Comment: because it can be tricked; creating directory with space will lead to creating symlink which was not intended to be there. Code logic can be abused

Answer (score 1):

Following block will create links as you explained.

If you want to filter out some names from /tmp ; use `-name` switch for find.

If you want greater depth symlinked adjust/remove `-maxdepth` switch

```
cd / 
find /tmp/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ln -s {} \;
```

To make these links you need write permissions on /

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so, Job done thanks to everyone for your hints.

Here is my simple solution:

```
 for i in $(ls); do dir=$i; ln -s /tmp/$dir /$dir; done
```

Et voila :D

Thank you, StackExchange community once again ;-)

Comment: Note that this is likely to fail horribly on filenames that contain spaces.

Comment: Indeed, I do not have any directory with spaces in name on my case.
But yep, ls will just interpret each part of the directory name as a unique directory, so the solution is just to add "" in this case X) Just tested and work fine on my RHEL :D.

But thanks for this comment which could be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have write permissions to the directory where you want the symbolic link to be created. Bear in mind that /tmp is (usually) cleaned up at boot and may be cleaned periodically throughout the machine's uptime, so relying on things being around persistently in /tmp will bite you, sooner or later.

Comment: I think I didn't ask correctly my question. Indeed, I've all needed rights on this machine, I'm root on it.

But now, what I'm looking for, is to create a symbolic link on my root for each directories contain on /tmp ;-)

For exemple:

I have:

    /tmp/d1
    /tmp/d2
    /tmp/d...
    /tmp/dn

and I want to link these previous directories like this:

    /d1
    /d2
    /d...